# PHP Str_repeat for Different Result Everyloop

Tags: php, string, hash

im generating test-16DIGIT hash with PHP. But when i try print it to screen with "echo" it is generating same 5 results.

i want generate 5 different results for every one loop.

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 16) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//16 hanelik kodu buyutuyorum
$uret = generateRandomString();
$buyut = strtoupper($uret);
echo str_repeat("1:test-" . "$buyut" . "</br>",5);
?>
```

i already tried "array method" but it is not working. thank you..

as you can see for loop not working too for echo line after change str_repeat to for loop;

```
<?php

function generateRandomString($length = 16) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//16 hanelik kodu buyutuyorum
$uret = generateRandomString();
$buyut = strtoupper($uret);
for ($i = 1; ; $i++) {
    if ($i > 10) {
        break;
    }
echo "1:test-" . "$buyut" . "</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're only generating one random string and using it 5 times. You want to generate 5 random strings. Therefore, you must run `generateRandomString` 5 times. I recommend a `for` loop.

Comment: it is not working. i already tried that with while and for loop but same result. it is generating same 5 results.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problem ;

```
<?php
function rand_str($len, $norepeat = true)
{
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $max = strlen($chars) - 1;

    if ($norepeat && $len > $max + 1) {
        throw new Exception("Non repetitive random string can't be longer than charset");
    }

    $rand_chars = array();

    while ($len) {
        $picked = $chars[mt_rand(0, $max)];

        if ($norepeat) {
            if (!array_key_exists($picked, $rand_chars)) {
                $rand_chars[$picked] = true;
                $len--;
            }
        }
        else {
            $rand_chars[] = $picked;
            $len--;
        }
    }

    return implode('', $norepeat ? array_keys($rand_chars) : $rand_chars);   
}
$i = 10;
foreach(range(1,5) as $i) {
$uretec = rand_str(16);
$buyut = strtoupper($uretec);
echo "1:test-" . "$buyut" . "</br>";
}
?>
```